# Filtering in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How can I filter information in (example) column B and C that is associated with a keyword in column A? So, if I select 'Apples' in column A it will automatically filter any information in B and C that I have associated with 'Apples'. Say column A is 'Food item', B 'Restaurant' and C 'Retailer'. If I select Waffles' in A it then only shows all Restaurants and Retailers that are associated with 'Waffles'?

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin - I know I need 3 columns, column A needs to be filtered and B and C's results then need to automatically be updated to reflect the correct association?

Comment: Consider using AutoFilter:  http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html

Comment: But then it will only filter if I have the actually word from A also in cells B and C - which I won't. I need to know how to create a link between the specific text in A and the actual relevant cell in column B and C which will enable it to filter correctly. I want to be able to select criteria in A (e.g waffles) and as soon as I hit enter have B and C (restaurants and retailers) automatically display the names of those who sell waffles. So column B may turn out 'Waffle House' and C 'Tesco' but if I searched 'Fresh Fruit' B would be 'Indie Cafe' and C 'Tesco'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, select the data you want to sort. After this, use a function key `"Sort&Filter"` that you can find in `Home` section. And finally, choose `Custom sort...`. Here you can identify that you want to `Sort by` column A.